# How to get correct Cell Coordinate values

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to style my excel sheet rows upto certain column. 
number of Column are dynamically changes as per application. 
I can count the number of column by counting the array size like

```
$ColSize = sizeOf(excel_out)
```

now i want to style it like this

```
for ($i= 0 ; $i<= $highestRow;$i++)
    {
        if ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue() == 'Responses')
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.':'.$ColSize.$i)->applyFromArray($Heading2Style);


        }
    }
```

but it gives the error that "Invalid  cell coordinate" I guess it's not getting the alphabet count for columns it just getting numeric value per cell like 
eg : 21=> B1
     31=>C1 
. how can i get the correct coordinate value ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `$ColSize` to an alpha column address value using the static `stringFromColumnIndex()` helper method of the PHPExcel_Cell class

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A' . $i . ':' . PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($ColSize) . $i)
    ->applyFromArray($Heading2Style);
```

Comment: Great ! You are Guru of PHPExcel .

Comment: Can you guide me for one more quick question posted below.

Answer (score 2):

What is there into $ColSize? Maybe you need to use:

```
 $columnString=PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($ColSize);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.':'.$columnString.$i)->applyFromArray($Heading2Style);
```